# I cant connect to tor websites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, windows, website

i have already seen similar questions asked in this website but it is always answered by the site is "actually" down.my problem is different.the site i am trying to access shows"

> Unable to connect
>   Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at xxxxxx.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web.
```

***the problem of mine is that my friends can access this site ...while i cant so it is not down.also i have been able to access this site a few hours ago***.so where is the problem?

`tor log:
7/20/2016 22:51:18 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
7/20/2016 22:51:20 PM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
7/20/2016 22:51:22 PM.500 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
7/20/2016 22:51:22 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
7/20/2016 22:51:23 PM.900 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
7/20/2016 22:51:24 PM.000 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
7/20/2016 22:52:38 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later).`

***it appears that with time i am unable to connect to more and more sites***

Comment: What does your Tor log say? Please append it to your question.

Comment: i have done it.

Comment: no it is not duplicate the other question had a problem that the sites were down....however my sites are confirmed not down

Comment: It's obvious you didn't read the answers then :)

Comment: i read them i dont have any of those problems...i checked it

Comment: ["If you can connect to one .onion address, then there is no reason on your end why you could not connect to all of them."](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/7090/12737)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42762/discussion-between-swapnava-chaudhuri-and-canonizing-ironize).