# I can't use the Tor search, or go to darknet

Tags: configuration, windows, help, blocked

When I run DISCONNECT.ME to search, it's redirected to DuckDuckGo, and if I enter an onion address, I receive a 404 error. I am new with this browser and I think that the configuration is not right.
My torrc file have a long list of obfs4 bridges and at the end says:

DataDirectory C:\Users\M...\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\M...\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\M...\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
HiddenServiceStatistics 0
UseBridges 1

The Tor Circuit actually is stackexchange.com with a bridge obfs4of Sweden and IP from U.S.A. and Netherlands

I included Tor in the Firewall, but I think that anyway is being blocked somehow or somewhere. Please tell me in detail how to configure the browser and the PC, including opening the ports for use it. I want to go to the darknet and .onion places.

Answer (score 2):

1. "When I run DISCONNECT.ME to search, it's redirected to DuckDuckGo"

Disconnect.me is redirecting to DuckDuckGo while they work on restoring their Google search syndication, it was falling back to Bing syndication which was providing less than helpful results so it will now redirect to DuckDuckGo.

2. "if I enter an onion address, I receive a 404 error."

404 is a server reported error (e.g. the onion service is saying it can't find a file), it is likely that the onion site in question is down or broken. Try loading https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/ if that works then theres no reason you shouldn't be able to load any other onion site. See also [Why can't I open most of the onion sites?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6546/why-cant-i-open-most-of-the-onion-sites)

Answer (score -1):

You *must avoid* using *any* clearnet-proxy for accessing Darknet, not just Tor. It ruins the darknet concept totally and fully exposes you. If you need more deep explaination I can tell you why

Comment: Where does he mention using a clearnet proxy?

Comment: @SuperSluether I've heard of Disconnect.me to be a darknet-to-clearnet proxy and search too. Am I wrong?

Comment: Disconnect Search is a proxy to other search engines, but I don't see anything about a darknet proxy. They offer a tracer/malware blocker, VPN services, and private search (the default in Tor Browser): https://disconnect.me/

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answer. I don't even know what is a clearnet-proxy. Does Disconnect.me work only with other search engines? What about my impossibility to enter in the dark net? I'll really appreciate any detailed explanation. I'm a PC technician, but I know nothing about TOR configurations. Thanks.

Comment: @Monka do you able to use other darknet sites? like Facebook facebookcorewwwi.onion ? Source here https://www.facebook.com/notes/protect-the-graph/making-connections-to-facebook-more-secure/1526085754298237/

Comment: @Monka You're welcome! I'm glad to help! If you have more question - feel free to ask them in Facebook, my profile is linked in my StackExchange profile

Comment: Thanks. I went to your profile, and there is a lot of useful info about TOR.

Comment: @Monka https://facebook.com/avesnin feel free to message me with your questions